# Execute Multiple test DLLs with Nunit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-2.5

I have multiple Nunit test DLL's like a_test.dll, b_test.dll, c_test.dll.

Whenever I need to execute the these test projects, I need to load them individually in the Nunit application and execute them.

Can I add them all at once and execute?

Comment: I never use the Nunit test runner - I'd either go with some free test-runner like TestDriven.net or with the integrated runner in Resharper (my choice for VS2010) - in VS11 the integrated testrunner handles NUnit fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the test runner included with ReSharper.  You can do ReSharper > Unit Tests > Run All Tests From Solution, or Ctrl+U, Ctrl+L and it will run all of your unit tests in each project.

Comment: Not every one have reSharper :( Do you know free/opensource tool that integrates into VS and lets you run nunit tests?

Comment: I was just saying that's what I use.  It's reasonably priced enough that I would buy it myself if my employer wouldn't.  I'm so hooked on it I couldn't imagine developing without it.

Comment: Actually, me too. Waste of time not to work with R# or CodeRush. It was piece of improvement after I switched from MonoDevelop :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a repetetive task and you're have to load libraries each time you run nunit.exe, load them once and save as solution (.nunit file).

Also, if you have the code of those libraries - you may unite all projects to a solution, and then open it with nunit.

As for now it can't load multiple dlls no from open dialog and no as a parameters from command line.